# SSIS Excel Export Sheetname Error

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm having an issue where I am trying to export an excel file from SSIS. The Error i get is `[Excel Destination [202]] Error: Opening a rowset for "Report$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.`

I've set it to delay validation and deleted and recreated the file and excel connection string a few times. The package is suppose to create a new file based on the date and time it runs which works fine. Its just having an issue with the Sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says that SSIS Package does not find the "Report" sheet from excel file.

Worksheet (Excel File) which you created needs to have sheet named "Report". I guess that you are doing this to load the fresh data in this file.Instead of this, create a template with sheet name "Report" with the blank records but with fields as required and create the connection pointing this template excel file, then fill this data and COPY this file to another folder and rename the file with as per your file naming convention (eg. file_yyyymmdd.xls). each time, you need to copy this blank template excel file to location where ssis package will load data into it.

Comment: worked a treat! you'd think something like this would work without having to do this! but thanks!